# Why is base constructor available via curly braces but not via parentheses?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, constructor

I've come across the following issue. Here is a simple piece of code:

```
struct Base {
  Base(int x) : x_{x} {}

  int get() { return x_; }

private:
  int x_ = 0;
};

struct Derived : Base {};

int main() {
  Derived d{5}; // Works fine
  std::cout << d.get() << std::endl;

  Derived dd(5); // Won't work
  std::cout << dd.get() << std::endl;
}
```

I have a base class which has a user-defined constructor and a derived one. As far as I know, it is necessary to bring the parent's constructor into the derived scope in order to make it available for the derived, so it's worth mentioning I haven't done that. So I can't really understand, why I can invoke the parent's constructor with curly braces but cannot with parentheses. Does anyone have an answer?

Remarkably, the code won't compile with the latest GCC or Clang, but works just fine with MSVC.

Comment: Always post complete error along with your question.

Comment: aggregate initialization... C++20 should allow `(..)` syntax though.

Comment: The program works with all compilers in c++20. See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/a3ErMM35q)

Comment: Why didn't it work with older standards though?..

Comment: @Kaiyakha Because older standard didn't allow it. See [P0960: Allow initializing aggregates from a parenthesized list of values](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0960r3.html) and the dupes.

Comment: @user12002570 I see, seems like cppref hasn't been updated on this issue yet. These documents are far harder to seek :)

Comment: Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Use `'\n'` to end a line unless there's a good reason not to.